# ADO.NET : Error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

i am trying to bind data to   Gridview  and  getting this error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

this is my simple  code

```
 string cs = "data source =.; initial catalog= MyDB;  integrated security= SSPI";
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_Dept", con);
 con.Open();
 GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 GridView1.DataBind();
 con.Close();
```

in SQl management studio i have rechecked  db  name and its same as mentioned in code

I found some related questions but those did not work for me so posting mine one ,  Please help me with  it,

Comment: Perhaps you have typo. You have missed semicolon after DB name.

Comment: sorry missed that while   formatting , its there in code

Comment: OK, have you mixed authentication mode?

Comment: In Sql Server Management Studio what is the value of the Server Name textbox when you log in the database?

Comment: @Steve Server Name:  MyName-PC\SQLEXPRESS   ,Authentication :  Windows Authentication

Comment: Then change your Data Source to Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install SQL Server Express the setup propose to create a [named instance](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165614%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx), and by default, this named instance, is called SQLEXPRESS.

When you want to connect to this `named instance` it is required to specify the name.
So, in your case your connection string should be changed to

```
"Data Source =.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=SSPI";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define `SqlConnection` string in your web.config(in web applications) or app.config(in windows form application).
Simply define like this -

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
         <add name="Connection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial   Catalog=DBName;Trusted_connection=yes;User ID=''; Password=''"/
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

then access this code in you .cs form using

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString.ToString());
```

and after this you can use `SqlConnection` object `con` in you whole form.